# PhoneGap add wp8 platform requires MSBuild x86

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild

When trying to add the wp8 platform to a project, using:

phonegap local build wp8

It fails. Requiring msbuild x86.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.WindowsPhon
e.v8.0.Overrides.targets(15,9): error : Building Windows Phone application using
 MSBuild 64 bit is not supported. If you are using TFS build definitions, change
 the MSBuild platform to x86. [C:\funiz\platforms\wp8\Funiz.csproj]
ERROR: MSBuild failed to create .xap when building cordova-wp8 for debugging.

This is a Windows 8.1 machine, with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, Update 2 RC.

The PATH environment variable is set to:

C:\Users\Yoram Kornatzky\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

I tried removing the Frame64 element from the PATH. But it still fails.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified the build template you are using. But if you are using DefaultTemplate in your team build definition, change value of parameter "MSBuild Platform" from Auto to X86

Comment: Problem is that I am trying to do it with the PhoneGap command line. Without any use to templates, so it is probably the default template. No use of TFS or team definitions. When I opened the project in Visual Studio and changed the build platform to X86, it still did not work. Probably because the project was not built in full, and Visual Studio complained on the Command not being imported. I need a way to tell the PhoneGap command line to use the MSBuild of X86. Any idea?

Comment: So you have set the of your Platform of all your projects to x86? Try out setting the following variable PlatformTarget=x86 in the Custom constants field from Advance Compilation option dialog.

Comment: Indeed, I have been able to move forward. But now there is the error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.WindowsPhon
e.Common.targets(110,5): error : The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed. But It is installed. I even added a reference path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Are you sure you have 32 bit version of Silverlight SDK? From the error, it looks like you have 64 bit version installed.

PS: If you think my answer has fixed your problem please Mark it as answer. Cheers

Comment: Here is the link to 32 bit installation of Silverlight 4 SDK 32 bit version http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15636

Comment: Still complains with the same effort, after installing the 32 bit version of Silverlight 4 SDK.